# Numerically, how exactly is the calculation of complex numbers is done?

Tags: complex-numbers, numerical-methods

For example, in python I can do $(1 + 2i)^{3 + 4i}$ by

```
print((1 + 2j)**(3 + 4j))
```

and I get: `(0.129009594074467+0.03392409290517014j)`.

It's fine, but how is it possible? I mean, what is the algorithm (and background theory of it) doing the complex calculations numerically?

I can find many articles about floating point algorithms, but can't find a good reference describing how the complex numbers are handled numerically.

### Edit

In fact, this question arose from the fact that we can get $i ^ i$ in the same way. I highly doubt a programming language is smart enough to derive $e^{-π/2}$, and thus is this question.

Comment: In general, if $z_1, z_2\in \mathbb C$, then we write $z_n=r_ne^{i\theta_n}$ where $r_n=|z_n|$, and then the computation is reasonably straight forward.

Comment: @lulu But is it numerically precise and / or computationally efficient in a modern processor?

Comment: "...reasonably straight forward" except of course that $e^{i\theta_1z_2}$ is defined only up to multiplication by arbitrary powers of $e^{i2\pi z_2}.$

Comment: @Arthur Is there another approach?  True, this method forces us to compute an arctangent, which I'd expect to be pretty slow.  Haven't thought about how that is optimized...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I kind of suppose that complex128 is stored as two float64 numbers. Thus, I'm not sure if the Euler's formula conversion is done numerically. In fact, I suppose there must be a legitimate reference that describes how the complex calculations must be done genreally.

Comment: The Python source code is on GitHub. The complex arithmetic seems to be implemented here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/cmathmodule.c

Comment: Computing $\tan^{-1}(y/x)$ is just fine if you stick to those $(x,y)$ whose ray is sufficiently close to the positive $x$-axis, contained in an angular sector centered on the positive $x$-axis of angular radius not much larger than $\pi/4$, i.e. $x>0$, $-1-\delta < y/x < 1+\delta$. And of course there are similar choices for angles sufficiently close to the positive $y$-axis, to the negative $x$-axis, and to the negative $y$-axis.

Comment: @lulu : The `atan2` function is a basic one that is used to implement other inverse trigonometric functions, so it is highly optimized and not slower than a sinus or exponential evaluation.

Comment: @LutzLehmann  That makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Julia](https://julialang.org/) is a programming language designed for mathematical computing, so it is a reasonable example of how complex exponentiation is handled in general. I will link the relevant source code at the end of this answer, but only a few lines of code are actually needed to understand how it works. They start at line 845, used for calculating $z^p$ when both $z$ and $p$ are complex:

```
        pᵣ, pᵢ = reim(p)
        r = abs(z)
        θ = angle(z)
        rᵖ = r^pᵣ * exp(-pᵢ*θ)
        ϕ = pᵣ*θ + pᵢ*log(r)
              ...
        return rᵖ * cis(ϕ)
```

Most of this is self-explanitory. , On line 636 we see that `angle(z)` is just arctan and on line 565, `cis(x)` is defined as $e^{ix}$.

```
angle(z::Complex) = atan(imag(z), real(z))
```

[Source: Julia/Complex.jl (github)](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/83592cfcbfbfa2849a217005ece921d36feb8e73/base/complex.jl)

Comment: Is Julia's `atan` equivalent to the function that most math libraries call `atan2`?

Comment: sort of! In this case it would be. Julia uses multiple dispatch, which means `atan(x)` is in some sense a different function entirely from `atan(y,x)`. The gory details are here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/99225ab1d11925b8e904b0b12f1ee8b0f6946660/base/special/trig.jl

Comment: Ah, okay. so it really is using Euler's formula. Thanks.